# Android license check using LVL - put your code inside the run() method or elsewhere

Tags: android

I am planning to use the Android License Verification Library (LVL) in my new paid app.

I am using the sample code provided in SDK. Do I need to move my code which is currently inside onCreate() method to this run() method:

```
private void displayResult(final String result) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ***// Move code that was in onCreate() here????***
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this IO session on LVL http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/evading-pirates-and-stopping-vampires-using-license-verification-library-in-app-billing-and-app-engine.html